# Unity 'You are not authorized to set the license key' error for Google Play in-app purchases

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, licensing

When I try to set the license key in Unity for in-app purchases it says I'm not authorized, I'm signed into the Keystore too. I got the license key from 'Monetization setup' tab from Google Play Console instead of the 'Services and API' tab that it tells you get it from as that no longer exists (so Unity fix that please) so I assume it's the correct licensing key. Any ideas why I'm not authorized?

[image]

Comment: Would like to know thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this isn't needed.
You should be able to just fill this out on the Unity Dashboard (https://dashboard.unity3d.com/gaming/) in Projects > Project Settings > General

See this post for more info:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/purchase-you-are-not-authorized-to-set-the-license-key-google-play.954261/